# Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception: 2

Tags: java, exception, multidimensional-array

I get errors when after i enter the exits it says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
```

Im terrible at programming so please bear with me

```
import java.util.*;

public class Highway{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Total number of the exits");
        int p=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The first exit");
        int i=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The second exit");
        int j=input.nextInt();

        int[]A= new int[p];

        for(int w=0;w<=p;i++) {


            A[i]=(int )(java.lang.Math.random() * 20 + 1);
            System.out.println(A[w]);
        }
    }

    static void Distance(int i, int j, int[] A) {
    // a is the array of distance
    // this find the  distances between i and j
        int distance = 0;

        if(j>i){
        for(int k = i; k<=j;k++) {

                distance=distance+A[k];
        }

                distance=distance-A[i];

        }

        if(i>j){
            for (int m = j; m<=i; m++){distance=distance+A[m];
            }
                distance=distance-A[j];
            }

            System.out.println("The distance of the first"+i+" and second exit"+j+" is"+distance);

        }
}
```

Comment: where is the stacktrace ?

Comment: Also, have you tried stepping through the code to see which line throws the exception?

Answer (score 4):

Your loop iterates until `p` inclusive, that's where you get the error!
The size of the array is `p` and the indices you should iterate are 0,...,p-1 plus you're incrementing `i` instead of `w`.

Modify:

```
for(int w=0;w<=p;i++)
```

to:

```
for(int w=0;w<p;w++)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your for loop to following

```
for(int w=0;w<p;w++) {


        A[w]=(int )(java.lang.Math.random() * 20 + 1);
        System.out.println(A[w]);
    }
```

The only changes I have done here is in the for condition because if size of array is p then the array values can be accessed at 0,1,...,p-1. Also, you need to increment `w` instead of `i` in the for loop

Also, within the array you are updating `A[i]` instead of `A[w]`

Comment: @alfasin in that answer `w`  isn't getting incremented. Moreover, the user is updating `A[i]` and then printing `A[w]` which will show him similar error again.

Comment: @alfasin Hope this clarifies for others as well :)